# How can I safely configure AppEngine sockets w/ Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I'd like to put a Redis server on Google Compute Engine and speak to it via AppEngine's socket support. The only problem is that there doesn't seem to be a specific firewall rule that says "this AppEngine application can access this host/port and no other".

There are some rules at instance setup time that describe whether the instance has access to task queues, etc, but not the inverse.

So my question is: how can I restrict port access to a Redis service only to a single AppEngine application?

Comment: The alternatives here are: 1) to put it on a public IP and add a long random password to Redis, or 2) go through the pain of setting up stunnel authentication for it, but I'd prefer to speak vanilla Redis securely to an AppEngine application.

Comment: there may be a service account authentication (e.g. 123845678986@project.gserviceaccount.com ), may worth it to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you can not. AppEngine is a shared IP space with all the other apps, just like shared hosting. You need to use application level authentication such as OAuth to get the proper restrictions in place.