# In Google cloud can i restrict the connection of my compute engine instances from App engine only?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

As by default according to `google cloud platorm docs`, if someone makes a project and in that project suppose there are `n` number of `instances (compute + app engine)`, then no one from outside can connect to any instance until and unless he/she has sat an additional `firewall rule` to accept traffic from `outside IP ranges`. Actually I wanted to connect my `compute engine` instances from my `app engine` only and i saw below two questions where i thought that may be i am not thinking in the right direction

1. This question here on SO [google-app-engine-communicate-with-compute-engine-over-internal-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155795/google-app-engine-communicate-with-compute-engine-over-internal-network)
       where in the answer the person wrote that

   > There isn't currently a way to setup a private network between GCE and
   >   GAE
2. One more question defined here
       [how-can-i-safely-configure-appengine-sockets-w-google-compute-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285059/how-can-i-safely-configure-appengine-sockets-w-google-compute-engine?rq=1)
       also here in the answer the person wrote that

   > In short you can not. AppEngine is a shared IP space with all the
   >   other apps, just like shared hosting.

**Can anyone please tell me am i missing something i am really confused now what is right and what is wrong** ??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict compute engine to accept requests only from app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914076/how-to-restrict-compute-engine-to-accept-requests-only-from-app-engine)